# HTML Video right context menu - hide only loop and show controls

Tags: javascript, html, menu

When you right click on the video to show context menu, I would like to hide first two options  (**Loop** and **Show controls**), I'm only able to find solutions to completely hide context menu...

Does anyone know what is the proper tag so those two option won't show up?

Example (right click on the video):

```js
var figure = jQuery(".video").hover( hoverVideo, hideVideo );

function hoverVideo(e) {  
    jQuery('video', this).get(0).play(); 
}

function hideVideo(e) {
    jQuery('video', this).get(0).pause(); 
}
```

```css
    #videosList {
 max-width: 600px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video {
  background-image: url('https://img.youtube.com/vi/nZcejtAwxz4/maxresdefault.jpg');
  height: 330px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/* Hide Play button + controls on iOS */
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="videosList">           

<div class="video">
    <video class="thevideo" loop preload="none">
      <source src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://giant.gfycat.com/VerifiableTerrificHind.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible. You can't change the items in the context menu. You can only remove it entirely. If you want to hide these items, the best way to do it would be to hide the context menu entirely and replace it with your own, custom context menu.

Comment: That actually isn't bad solution at all, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out how to solve this purely by accident, by placing one overlay div over it with CSS:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
```

Video has to be **position: relative;** obviously.

I've used that div as a container for my text, but it also solves my video controls problem.

Comment: Thank you so much op, I was looking for this so long.

Comment: Hi, @DearBee I couldn't be able to make this work. On which div you placed your overlay? I tried putting an overlay on your code with the styles you mentioned, but the controls option won't hide. Can you update the HTML of the code? You might have forgotten this since it's been two years, but I would really appreciate it if you just make this same code work.

Comment: Never mind I made a mask to cover the video.

Comment: Sry, I didn't read this since now, but I'm glad you made it.